# Compute the total derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis

Using the definition, prove that the function $f : R^2 → R$ defined by
$f(x, y) = xy$ is differentiable on $R^2$. Compute the total derivative at each point of $R^2$.

The partial derivatives exist and are continuous. I know how to compute at a certain point,but I could not find the total derivative at each point.

Comment: the total derivative is just dual to the gradient; $$df_{(x,y)}(\delta x,\delta y)=\delta x\cdot\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)(x,y)\,+\delta y\cdot\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)(x,y)\,\delta y$$

Answer (score 0):

$d f(x,y) = {\partial f \over \partial x} dx + {\partial f \over \partial y} dy = y dx + x dy$.

Answer (score 0):

The total derivative of $f$ is
\begin{align}
f' 
&= J f \\
&= (\partial_x f, \partial_y f) \\
&= (\mbox{grad } f )^t \\
&= (y, x)
\end{align}
where $Jf$ is the Jacobian of $f$ which reduces to the transposed gradient for scalar valued functions.

Comment: How do I show the function is differentiable by using the definition of differentiability @mvw

Comment: Which definition do you use?